# Customize mail content in Moodle

Tags: moodle

Moodle can send emails for all kinds of messages. I just do not understand how the mails are composed.
For example: When a course is requested in Moodle I receive a mail with "User XY has requested a course".
When I get a private message sent, I get a mail with the message.

I do not want the content of the private message to be sent. Rather something like "you have a new message". The same goes for the email which is sent for forum posts.
All other mailtemplates should not be changed.

Someone has an idea how this could be implemented?

I have tried to fix the problem via a language adjustment, but could not achieve the desired result here.

Answer (score 1):

You have some control of site wide email notifications via

Site admin > General > Messaging > Notifications

Or for personal notifications via

Click on your user name (usually at the top) > Preferences > Notification Preferences

Other than that you will need to customise the text via Site admin > General > Language > Language Customisation

Note : Plugins "Should" use the messaging API so you can switch on/off email, but some custom plugins ignore it and go straight to email